# Geting multiple Records in update in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I am developing this website that requires me to combine two models in one view where they have one to many relationship between them. The models name is Home and Image meaning Home has many Images but Image only has one Home.

I have manged to combine The view together but the problem that i encountering is to get all of the images. For example i have 6 images i want to display them or if i have 5 images i want to display them.

**Home Controller UpdateMethod**

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $home=$this->loadModel($id);
        $image=Image::model()->findByAttributes(array('homeId'=>$home->id));

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Home'],$_POST['Image'])){
            $home->attributes=$_POST['Home'];
            $image->attributes=$_POST['Image'];

            $valid=$home->validate();
            $valid=$image->validate() && $valid;

            if($valid){
                if($home->save()){
                    $image->save();

                }
            }
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'home'=>$home,
            'image'=>$image,
        ));


    }
```

**My _form.php** to join them together

```
<div class="form">

    <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'home-form',
        // Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
        // controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
        // There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller code.
        // See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    )); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($home); ?>


    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($image,'imageUrl'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($image,'imageUrl',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>100)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($image,'imageUrl'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($home,'recentEvents'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($home,'recentEvents',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>100)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($home,'recentEvents'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($home,'introduction'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textArea($home,'introduction',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($home,'introduction'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($home->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
    </div>

    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

**Update** I had FindByattribues instead of FindAllByAttribues in the model so now it is returning an array. Now how to process that array in the view?

Answer (score 0):

Okay i figured it out by myself posting this to maybe help someone who needs it. I the view i did the following.

```
<?php
    foreach($image as $image){
        ?>

        <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($image,'imageUrl'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->textField($image,'imageUrl',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>100)); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($image,'imageUrl'); ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: If you set up the model relations right you should also be able to use `$home->images` (or however you the relation is called). The relation should be something like this `'images' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Image', 'homeId'),` and it should be defined in home. So in the view you could also use '$home->images as $image' or define images in the controller using `$images = $home->images`. Not that it is wrong the way you do it know, just figured to throw it out there. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#declaring-relationship